# Limit row selection to 3 in datatables

Tags: jquery

I'm currently using the jQuery datatables plugin and was wondering if there is any way I could limit row selection to just 3. Right now the user can select an infinite amount of rows. Here is a jsfiddle of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/EfFA2/

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
$('#example5').dataTable( {
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bSort": true,
        "bInfo": true,
        "bAutoWidth": false
    } );
    /* Add/remove class to a row when clicked on */
    $('#example5 tr').click( function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('row_selected');
    } );
 } );
 $('#example5').css('min-height','300');  

$('.btn_r').click(function(){
  $('.row_selected').removeClass('row_selected')
})
​
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
$('#example5').dataTable( {
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bSort": true,
        "bInfo": true,
        "bAutoWidth": false
    } );
    /* Add/remove class to a row when clicked on */
    $('#example5 tr').click( function() {
        if($('.row_selected').length < 3 || 
           $(this).hasClass('row_selected')) {
            $(this).toggleClass('row_selected');
        }
    } );
 } );
 $('#example5').css('min-height','300');  

$('.btn_r').click(function(){
  $('.row_selected').removeClass('row_selected')
})
```

​ [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EfFA2/1/)

Answer (score 5):

Add this as an option:

```
"iDisplayLength": 3
```

Full example:

```
$('#example5').dataTable({
    "bPaginate": true,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": true,
    "bSort": true,
    "bInfo": true,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "iDisplayLength": 3
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EfFA2/3/

If, on the other hand, [Beno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/320956/beno)'s interpretation of your question is correct, modify your click handler to this:

```
$('#example5 tr').click(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    if (self.hasClass('row_selected')) {
        self.removeClass('row_selected');
    } else {
        if ($('#example5 tr.row_selected').length < 3) {
            $(this).addClass('row_selected');
        }
    }
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EfFA2/4/

Comment: i think the asker is looking to limit the number of rows that can be selected rather than the rows that are displayed