# Limit row selection in DT Table in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am currently trying to limit my selection in a DataTable in Shiny to just two rows - I want the table to not allow the user to click on more than rows (but also to have the ability to deselect them afterwards).

```
library(DT)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(12,
             dataTableOutput('table')
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(iris, 
                                    options = list(selection = "multiple")
    )
  }
)
```

The row selection is currently on multiple mode, which works, but I don't want the selection to exceed two rows.

Comment: You can set row selection mode to either single or multiple with options in DT. Check DT documentations. To limit 2 rows you will need to write some code to observe row selection events, and deselect extra rows if needed. The extensive documentation of DT covered all of these topic, with examples and code samples, though it could be a little bit scattered around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: Does not seem to work anymore, since 04.2022 or earlier.

You could either solve it via javascript, which you may have seen already:
[Limit row selection to 3 in datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13389666/limit-row-selection-to-3-in-datatables)

Or you update the datatable in Shiny:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(12,dataTableOutput('tbl'))
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    reset <- reactiveValues(sel = "")
    output$tbl <- DT::renderDataTable({
      input$tbl_rows_selected
      datatable(iris, selection = list(mode = 'multiple', selected = reset$sel))
    })
    
    observe({
      if(length(input$tbl_rows_selected) > 2){
        reset$sel <- setdiff(input$tbl_rows_selected, input$tbl_row_last_clicked)
      }else{
        reset$sel <- input$tbl_rows_selected
      }
    })
  }
)
```

This solution might be less clean, but a bit easier to understand.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I tried to quickly run your code, but when I directly put it in R, it doesn't work. Nonetheless, I'll try the approach that you have recommended - it looks like it should do the job. Once again, thank you!

Comment: ok, i just tried again, for me it worked. You have DT installed?`Does it give any error messages?

Comment: Yes, I have the DT package installed. It runs, but it gives a blank UI. Nonetheless, I implemented it in my main application and everything worked fine.

Comment: When I runt his code, I get endless "Processing..." message. Something appears to have changed.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem @GiovanniColitti. Currently, i dont know another solution, i will make an edit.

Comment: The code does not work when clicking on one of the rows in the table.

Comment: Correct. See the comments above yours and the update comment in the post.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you want but I've changed a bit Tonio's answer, it may help someone else.

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(12,dataTableOutput('tbl'))
    ),
    textOutput('selected_rows')
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    reset <- reactiveValues(sel = "")
    output$tbl <- DT::renderDataTable({
      datatable(iris, selection = list(mode = 'multiple', selected = reset$sel))
    })
    
    observe({
      if(length(input$tbl_rows_selected) > 2){
        reset$sel <- NULL
      }else{
        reset$sel <- input$tbl_rows_selected
      }
    })
    
    output$selected_rows <- renderText({input$tbl_rows_selected})
  }
)
```