# How to select max number of cells in shiny DT datatable

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, datatables, dt

Is there a way to select up to certain number of cells in shiny DT datatable? Im talking about cells not rows.

```
library(shiny)
if (packageVersion('DT') < '0.1.3') devtools::install_github('rstudio/DT')
library(DT)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      h1('Client-side processing'),
      DT::dataTableOutput('x1')

    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$x1 = DT::renderDataTable(
      iris, server = FALSE,
      selection = list(mode = 'multiple',target="cell")
    )

  }
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit row selection in DT Table in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43805799/limit-row-selection-in-dt-table-in-shiny)

Comment: Im talking about cell selection not rows

Comment: replace row with cell and you should be good to go

Comment: I did that plus replacing target="cell" but i dont think that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with the help of the Select extension:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

callback <- c(
  "var tblID = $(table.table().node()).closest('.datatables').attr('id');",
  "var inputName = tblID + '_cells_selected:DT.cellInfo'",
  "",
  "table.on('select', function(e, dt, type, ix){",
  "  var selected = dt.cells({selected: true});",
  ## send selected cells to Shiny
  "  var indices = selected.indexes().toArray()", 
  "    .map(function(x){return {row: x.row+1, column: x.column};});",
  "  Shiny.setInputValue(inputName, indices);",
  ## deselect if more than 5 selected
  "  if(selected.count() > 5){",
  "    dt.cells(ix).deselect();",
  "  }",
  "});",
  "",
  # on deselect, also send selected cells to Shiny
  "table.on('deselect', function(e, dt, type, ix){",
  "  var selected = dt.cells({selected: true});",
  "  var indices = selected.indexes().toArray()", 
  "    .map(function(x){return {row: x.row+1, column: x.column};});",
  "  Shiny.setInputValue(inputName, indices);",
  "});"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  DTOutput("tbl"),
  br(),
  h3("Selected cells:"),
  verbatimTextOutput("selectedCells")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output[["tbl"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      iris[1:6,],
      selection = "none",
      extensions = "Select",
      callback = JS(callback),
      options = list(
        select = list(style = "multi", items = "cell")
      )
    )
  })

  output[["selectedCells"]] <- renderPrint({
    input[["tbl_cells_selected"]]
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```